# How to add internationalization support to Blogger and make the code recognize html?

Tags: javascript, html, internationalization, blogger

Below is the quote of answer by Mykhaylo Adamovych on topic "How to add internationalization support to Blogger?"

This code works, but there is one catch, 
when you add links to the text html won't recognize them, generally, none html codes are recognized in the text and they are written as they are.

Is it possible to make modification which would recognize codes?

> ... and here is implementation
>
> These should be set in html head of
>   your blog (Blog Design -> Edit HTML,
>   insert after <head>)
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://csjs.googlecode.com/files/csjs.i18n_1.0.0.js"></script>
> ```
>
> This is very post looks like:
>
> ```
> <!-- insert this as a title -->
> <div id='post1_div1' msgId='post1_msg1'> <!-- it is worth
> ```
>
> to add default text here due to some
>   programs that -->
>
> ```
> <!-- any HTML controls to be internationalized -->
> <div id='post1_div2' msgId='post1_msg2'><!-- operate blog
> ```
>
> content (like rss reader) will not
>   download script -->
>
> ```
> <!-- add language selector in the bottom of the post -->
> <div>
>     <a onclick="i18n.trigger('en')"
> ```
>
> style="display: inline; margin:
>   2px">en
>           ru
>           ua
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     i18n.load( {
>         'en' : {
>             'post1_msg1' : 'First Post',
>             'post1_msg2' : 'Post content'
>         },
>         'ua' : {
>             'post1_msg1' : 'Перше повідомлення',
>             'post1_msg2' : 'Текст повідомлення'
>         },
>         'ru' : {
>             'post1_msg1' : 'Первое сообщение',
>             'post1_msg2' : 'Текст сообщения'
>         }
>     });
>
>     /* bind all elements with internationalized messages to language
> ```
>
> change event */
>           jQuery('#post1_div1').bind('i18n',
>   i18n.update);
>           jQuery('#post1_div2').bind('i18n',
>   i18n.update);
>
> ```
>     /* fill elements with internationalized content */
>     i18n.trigger(null);
> </script>
> ```
>
> Due to blogger preprocessor newlines
>   should be removed between
>   <script></script>
>   tags.
>  I've used gvim and it
>   Shift+j magic keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some draft tool for internationalization, which works perfectly with blogger.

Link: http://i18nblog.blogspot.com/

Just put html code on the one tab and click on another ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to replace `jQuery(this).text` with `jQuery(this).html` inside the `update` function of the I18N plugin.

Comment: inside what?
I really don't know where to find it :/

Comment: Inside the file csjs.i18n_1.0.0.js file.

Comment: I found it and changed it but that didn't solve the problem.
Only difference with previous file is that now nothing is shown, before there would be text with all codes, dashes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to put HTML code inside messages? Common approach here is to design HTML page, then any simplest messages surround with div elements with unique ids to be able to manage them by script. You can create internationalized link like this:

```
<a href="http://google.com">
    <div id='post1_div2' msgId='post1_msg2'><!-- operate blog content (like some of rss reader) will not download script --></div>
</a>
```

Or could you describe original problem please?

Comment: I need it because I want to center text and put links into text.

p.s. I'm not so sure how to use this new code you gave me :/ 
Where to put it?

Comment: Could you provide designed html page here with text in english please? Designed means "I want to center text and put links into text" etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking for. But my problem is: when I use code I can't put any links into post text and can't use codes such as for centering text in post.

Comment: You shouldn't insert any HTML inside internationalization table. This should be only text. Here is more useful [example](http://code.google.com/p/csjs/wiki/csjs_i18n____Example2). Chief idea here is to design complete HTML page with styles, element positions etc. and then add alternative text using unique ids of your text snippets and specifying alternative translation to internationalization table.